# C++ Stretching an equalized image

Tags: c++, opencv, histogram, stretching

From an (2)equalized image I have to create a (3).

1. Original image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lqzbv.jpg
2. Equalized image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/obhbT.png
3. Equalized and Stretch image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4aPR.png

With OpenCV I could have used equalizeHist() that does both equalization and stretching.

So without using OPENCV, how can I do stretching from an equalization image. The equalization part is done below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <cstring>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

using namespace cv;

void imhist(Mat image, int histogram[])
{

    // initialize all intensity values to 0
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        histogram[i] = 0;
    }

    // calculate the no of pixels for each intensity values
    for (int y = 0; y < image.rows; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < image.cols; x++)
            histogram[(int)image.at<uchar>(y, x)]++;

}

void cumhist(int histogram[], int cumhistogram[])
{
    cumhistogram[0] = histogram[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < 256; i++)
    {
        cumhistogram[i] = histogram[i] + cumhistogram[i - 1];
    }
}

int main()
{
    // Load the image
    Mat image = imread("y1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    // Generate the histogram
    int histogram[256];
    imhist(image, histogram);


    // Caluculate the size of image
    int size = image.rows * image.cols;
    float alpha = 255.0 / size;

    // Calculate the probability of each intensity
    float PrRk[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        PrRk[i] = (double)histogram[i] / size;
    }

    // Generate cumulative frequency histogram
    int cumhistogram[256];
    cumhist(histogram, cumhistogram);

    // Scale the histogram
    int Sk[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        Sk[i] = cvRound((double)cumhistogram[i] * alpha);
    }

    // Generate the equlized image
    Mat new_image = image.clone();

    for (int y = 0; y < image.rows; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < image.cols; x++)
            new_image.at<uchar>(y, x) = saturate_cast<uchar>(Sk[image.at<uchar>(y, x)]);
    //////////////////////////////////////////

    // // Generate the histogram stretched image
    Mat str_image = new_image.clone();

    //for (int a = 0; a < str_image.rows; a++)
    //  for (int b = 0; b < str_image.cols; b++)

    // Display the original Image
    namedWindow("Original Image");
    imshow("Original Image", image);

    // Display equilized image
    namedWindow("Equalized Image");
    imshow("Equalized Image", new_image);


    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not vandalize your questions.

Answer (score 3):

The normal way to do this is to find your darkest pixel, and your brightest. You can do this in a singe loop iterating over all your pixels, pseudo-code like this:

```
darkest=pixel[0,0]   // assume first pixel is darkest for now, and overwrite later
brightest=pixel[0,0] // assume first pixel is lightest for now, and overwrite later
for all pixels
    if this pixel < darkest
       darkest = this pixel
    else if this pixel > brightest
       brightest = this pixel
    endif
end for
```

Simple enough. So, let's say the darkest and brightest are 80 and 220 respectively. Now you need to stretch this range 80..220 onto the full range 0..255.

So you subtract 80 from every pixel in your image to shift down to zero at the left end of the histogram, so your range is now 0..140. So now you need to multiply every pixel by 255/140 to stretch the right end out to 255. Of course, you can do both pieces of arithmetic in a single pass over your pixel array.

```
for all pixels
   newvalue = int((current value - darkest)*255/(brightest-darkest))
end for
```